# Test runtime classpath does not contain plugin metadata file 'plugin-under-test-metadata.properties'

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, testkit

I am upgrading gradle version to 6.8.1.For testing purpose. I am adding the dependency **testCompile gradleTestKit(**) in build.gradle but my intergation test case are failing with below error.
I tried upgrading to Junit 5, spock 2.0-groovy-2.5  & groovy 2.5.12.

*Code*:

```
def runner = GradleRunner.create()
            .withProjectDir(this.testDir)
            .withPluginClasspath()
```

**withPluginClasspath()** method getting the exception.

*Test case:*

```
def "Make sure a build runs successfully"() {
        when:
        def result = build 'compileJava'
```

*Error*:

```
Test runtime classpath does not contain plugin metadata file 'plugin-under-test-metadata.properties'
org.gradle.testkit.runner.InvalidPluginMetadataException: Test runtime classpath does not contain plugin metadata file 'plugin-under-test-metadata.properties'
    at org.gradle.testkit.runner.internal.PluginUnderTestMetadataReading.readImplementationClasspath(PluginUnderTestMetadataReading.java:44)
    at org.gradle.testkit.runner.internal.PluginUnderTestMetadataReading.readImplementationClasspath(PluginUnderTestMetadataReading.java:37)
    at org.gradle.testkit.runner.internal.DefaultGradleRunner.withPluginClasspath(DefaultGradleRunner.java:162)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding 'plugin-under-test-metadata.properties' file in my src/resources folder as I noticed classpath is reading from src folder.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by changing integration tests settings in build.gradle:

```
integTest {
    // old code had "configurations.testRuntime" at the end
    compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output + configurations.testRuntimeClasspath
}
```

Comment: what the actual.. thank you, I was upgrading a project from gradle 4 to gradle 7 and was scratching my head the entire time wondering what was wrong